# Is it possible to define command to execute in setup.py

Tags: python, daemon

I could like to let my daemon program to be auto-start after **setup.py install**

In shell, I can archive this via :

> update-rc.d kmsd defaults 21

In setup.py ([disutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html)), how to do that ?

Is it possible to do that or I can only let my users manually invoke this command after installation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I do this in my own code to pre-compile some libraries using a legacy build system.

Something like the following should work, though I should caveat it by saying I haven't tested the code below.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Command
import distutils.command.install as InstallCommand
from subprocess import call

class FinallyDoSomething(Command):
    description = "Do my custom stuff"
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        call(["update-rc.d", "kmsd", "defaults", "21"])

class NewInstall(InstallCommand):
    sub_commands = InstallCommand.sub_commands + [
            ('custom_install', None),]

setup(name='PackageName',
      version='0.1',
      #The rest of the setup config
      cmdclass={
          'install': NewInstall,
          'custom_install': FinallyDoSomething,
          },
      )
```